# Do we need language-agnostic tag here?

Tags: discussion

It seems that questions on Prog.SE are language-agnostic by default, and the tag is just unnecessary noise

There's [currently 29 questions with the tag](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic).

Anyone agree/disagree we should kill the tag?

Comment: I've gone through and removed the tags, with a link in the edit comment to this question. (Apologies that it looks like I've spammed the front page!)

Answer (score 3):

I don't disagree that we should kill the tag, but I do disagree if that means that we shouldn't ask language specific questions here.  They may not get answered right away, but there are enough opinionated Delphi, Python and C# programmers on the site that language minutiae is not beyond the scope or interests of the community.

Comment: To clarify, I didn't say that we *shouldn't* ask language specific questions, but simply that the *default* is that a question applies to any/all languages. If a question does apply to a specific language, it'll get [tagged](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/9498/what-is-the-best-orm-for-net) [appropriately](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/11175/have-you-tried-chronon-the-java-time-travelling-debugger-if-so-is-it-worth).

Answer (score 2):

I agree it is superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

No - it should not be *completely* killed.

Ok, so as in the comment above I removed the tag from most questions, but as I was going through I noticed three exceptions, where it seems relevant to keep the tag:

- [Language agnostic programming books](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/163/language-agnostic-programming-books)
- [What should I do to be language-agnostic?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1189/what-should-i-do-to-be-language-agnostic)
- [Language-agnostic libs every programmer should consider learning?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6442/language-agnostic-libs-every-programmer-should-consider-learning)

Since the topic of those tags is *specifically* about being language agnostic, (rather than it being a non-descriptive tag as in the other cases), I figured it makes sense to keep it there.

Hopefully others agree?

Comment: If it's in the title, does it need to be in a tag?

Comment: Compare the search results [for the tag](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=\[language-agnostic\]) vs [for the words](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=language+agnostic) - if you want to find questions specifically related to it, the tag cuts down the noise.